# If $a, b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $ae^{2it}+be^{-2it}$ is real, then $ae^{2it}+be^{-2it}=a'\cos(2t)+b'\sin(2t)$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm asked to show that

> If $a, b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $ae^{2it}+be^{-2it}$ is real, then $ae^{2it}+be^{-2it}=a'\cos(2t)+b'\sin(2t)$ for some $a',b'\in\mathbb{R}$

My work so far is as follows.
Recall that $e^{ix}:=\cos(x)+i\cdot \sin(x)$.

Assume that $ae^{2it}+be^{-2it}$ is real, then we expand each term using the identity provided. Hence,
\begin{align*}
ae^{2it}+be^{-2it}&\Leftrightarrow a\cos(2t)+i\cdot a\sin(2t)+b\cos(2t)-i\cdot b \sin(2t)\\
&\Leftrightarrow (a+b)\cdot \cos(2t)+(a-b)i\cdot \sin(2t)
\end{align*}
Where do I go from here to show that $(a+b)$ and $(a-b)$ are real? Also, what do I do about the $i$ in the second term?

Comment: Have you thought about happens when $t=0$ in your starting equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a,b \in \mathbb C$ , put $a=x_1+iy_1$ and $b=x_2+iy_2$ where $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb R$

So $a+b= (x_1+x_2)+i(y_1+y_2)$ and $a-b=(x_1-x_2)+i(y_1-y_2)$

$$ ae^{2it}+be^{-2it} = (a+b)\cos(2t)+i\cdot (a-b)\sin(2t)$$

$$ ae^{2it}+be^{-2it} = \{(x_1+x_2)+i(y_1+y_2)\}\cos(2t)+i\cdot \{(x_1-x_2)+i(y_1-y_2)\}\sin(2t)$$

$$ = (x_1+x_2)\cos(2t)+i(y_1+y_2)\cos(2t)+i(x_1-x_2)\sin(2t)-(y_1-y_2)\sin(2t)$$

$$ = \{(x_1+x_2)\cos(2t)-(y_1-y_2)\sin(2t)+i\{(y_1+y_2)\cos(2t)+(x_1-x_2)\sin(2t)\}$$

Since  $ae^{2it}+be^{-2it} \in \mathbb R $ ,

$$(y_1+y_2)\cos(2t)+(x_1-x_2)\sin(2t)=0$$

Thus $$ ae^{2it}+be^{-2it} = (x_1+x_2)\cos(2t)+(y_2-y_1)\sin(2t)$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $a=x+iy$ and $b=u+iv$, we have, using your calculations,

$\begin{multline}ae^{e^{2it}}+be^{-2it}=(a+b)\cos(2t)+(a-b)i\sin(2t)\\=(x+u)\cos(2t)+(y+v)i\cos(2t)+(x-u)i\sin(2t)-(y-v)\sin(2t)\end{multline}$.

Since the number is real, the imaginary part is 0. Therefore

$\begin{eqnarray}
ae^{e^{2it}}+be^{-2it}&=&(x+u)\cos(2t)+(y+v)i\cos(2t)+(x-u)i\sin(2t)-(y-v)\sin(2t)\\
&=&(x+u)\cos(2t)-(y-v)\sin(2t)\\
&=&Re(a+b)\cos(2t)-Im(a-b)\sin(2t)\\
\end{eqnarray}$